# Programmatically set SpringBoot Datasource

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, mariadb

I need to set two Datasources for my SpringBoot Application. Currently, the single Datasource working solution to deal (successfully) with timeouts on MariaDB server sets the following three parameters in application.properties

```
# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 60000
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
```

Various examples that I have checked using Java-based, Datasource configuration are in general as follows:

```
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DataSource userDataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource
          = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(
          env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("user.jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.pass"));

        return dataSource;
    }
```

The problem is that I don't know how to set testWhileIdle and validationQuery using the Datasource class since there are no respective methods and I don't see in MariaDB documentation any related option that can be passed as part of the JDBC URL.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Spring Boot with Tomcat then it will use `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` not `DriverManagerDataSource`. Change your dataSource method to return a `BasicDataSource` which has methods to set `testWhileIdle` and `validationQuery`.

```
@Primary
@Bean
public DataSource userDataSource() {

    BasicDataSource dataSource
      = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(
      env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("user.jdbc.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.pass"));
    dataSource.setTestWhileIdle(env.getProperty("jdbc.testWhileIdle"));
    dataSource.setValidationQuery(env.getProperty("jdbc.validationQuery"));


    return dataSource;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply  @shazin, which has sent me in the right direction, I hope. In my case seems to be org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource and the configuration apparently working looks like a simple
    #Primary
    #Bean(name="mainDatasource")
    #ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new DataSource();
    } ( AT replaced with #)

Answer (score 1):

```
...
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
...

@Primary
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DataSourceBuilder factory = DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
                .url(...)
                .username(...)
                .password(...)
                .driverClassName(...);
        return factory.build();
}
...
```